# How to convert this clause into prolog?

Tags: prolog

Clause:Every food is a meal OR Anything is a meal if it is a food
How do I convert this clause to Prolog language
this is my attempt:  `meal(X):-food(X)` 
I am unsure how to convert the clause "Anything is a meal if it is a food" to Prolog

Comment: Welcome to SO, you should look up more general solutions, I'm sure they exist.  this should help a little. what you are asking is: if food then it is a meal

Comment: Someone else in your class asked [the same question, but got an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55905560/how-can-i-create-this-rule-in-prolog).