# How can I create this rule in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

I need a help for create this rule in Prolog.

This is the question:
Create fact and rule for Prolog.

- burger is a food.
- sandwich is a food.
- pizza is a food.
- sandwich is a lunch.
- pizza is a dinner.
- every food is a meal OR Anything is a meal if it is a food.

ps. it's not homework, it's myself assignment i want know how to create this rule correctly.

```
food(burger).
food(sandwich).
lunch(sandwich).

dinner(pizza).

meal(X) :- food(X) ; ...
```

Comment: *every food is a meal* and *Anything is a meal if it is a food.* say the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

First, translate the English sentences to first-order logic sentences.

```
every food is a meal
=> forall X (food(X) -> meal(X))
```

```
anything is a meal if it is a food
=> if it is a food, it is a meal
=> if X is a food, X is a meal
=> forall X (food(X) -> meal(X))
```

Then, translate the first-order logic sentences to Prolog Horn clauses:

```
meal(X) :- food(X).
meal(X) :- food(X).
```

which is redundant and can be written just once instead.